# Sorting array by field in .net 2.0

Tags: arrays, sorting, c#-2.0

I have class StatusesInvestmentRow (from dataSource) where one of the field is ModifiedDate

```
Investment table:

Id int PK;
ModifiedDate datetime;
```

How can I sort this arrayby this date?

I found example with IComparable but StatusesInvestmentRow has DataRow type so it is not good way I think.

I have this and I can't change this:

```
  statInw = new GetAllInvestmentStatuses();
```

I want add something like:

```
  var newestStatusInvestment = statInv.Sort(comparerByDate)[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use DataTable's and DataView's own sorting and selecting functions [to do this](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_filter_sort.html).

Btw, your tag mentions .NET 2.0 but you're using the `var` keyword?

Comment: Those select functions return DataRow[]